# How to use do Homographic key matching using AKAZE in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, homography

```
import matplotlib as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load the image and convert it to grayscale
src = cv2.imread('A.jpg')
target = cv2.imread('B.jpg')

#cv2.imshow("Original", image)

def drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, matches,color,matchFlag):
  rows1 = img1.shape[0]
  cols1 = img1.shape[1]
  rows2 = img2.shape[0]
  cols2 = img2.shape[1]

  out = np.zeros((max([rows1,rows2]),cols1+cols2,3), dtype='uint8')

  # Place the first image to the left
  out[:rows1,:cols1] = np.dstack([img1, img1, img1])

  # Place the next image to the right of it
  out[:rows2,cols1:] = np.dstack([img2, img2, img2])

  # For each pair of points we have between both images
  # draw circles, then connect a line between them
  for match in matches:

      # Get the matching keypoints for each of the images
      img1_idx = match.queryIdx
      img2_idx = match.trainIdx

      # x - columns
      # y - rows
      (x1,y1) = kp1[img1_idx].pt
      (x2,y2) = kp2[img2_idx].pt

      # Draw a small circle at both co-ordinates
      # radius 4
      # colour blue
      # thickness = 1

      cv2.circle(out, (int(x1),int(y1)), 4, (255, 0, 0), 1)
      cv2.circle(out, (int(x2)+cols1,int(y2)), 4, (255, 0, 0), 1)

      # Draw a line in between the two points
      # thickness = 1
      # colour blue

      cv2.line(out, (int(x1),int(y1)), (int(x2)+cols1,int(y2)), color, 1)


  # Show the image
  cv2.imshow('Matched Features', out)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  cv2.destroyWindow('Matched Features')

  # Also return the image if you'd like a copy
  return out

# initialize the AKAZE descriptor, then detect keypoints and extract
# local invariant descriptors from the image
detector = cv2.AKAZE_create()
(kps1, descs1) = detector.detectAndCompute(src, None)
print("keypoints: {}, descriptors: {}".format(len(kps1), descs1.shape)) 
(kps2, descs2) = detector.detectAndCompute(target, None)
print("keypoints: {}, descriptors: {}".format(len(kps2), descs2.shape))

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)  #Brute Force matching
matches = bf.knnMatch(descs1, descs2, k=2)

# Apply ratio test
good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.9 * n.distance:
        good.append([m])

# cv2.drawMatchesKnn expects list of lists as matches.
print(len(good))

if len(good)>5:
  src_pts = np.float32([ kps1[m[0].queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1,1,2)
  dst_pts = np.float32([ kps2[m[0].trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1,1,2)

  M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
  matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

  h,w,_ = src.shape
  pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
  dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

  img2 = cv2.polylines(target,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

else:
  print("Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),10))

  matchesMask = None

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(src, kps1, target, kps2, good, None, matchesMask=matchesMask, flags=2)
```

I am trying to do homographic matching in python opencv3.1, but i am not able to apply mask on the image, and I get

> SystemError: error return without exception set

How can apply a mask to keypoints matches and ignore the outliers using RANSAC?